# At which point the true/ false will be evaluated in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I know the question might sound stupid but here is my question:

```
l = 1
r = 2
while l < r:
    while l < 50:
        l += 1
    print(l)
    l += 1
    # l < r will be evaluated to true up to this point
print(l)
```

Why is printing the variable l will result in 50, 51 instead of both 50 or 1? Is the condition will only be checked after an iteration?

Is python made this way? In order to break from it, I must add an if statement like this?

```
l = 1
r = 2
while l < r:
    while l < 50:
        l += 1
    print(l)
    if l > 2:
       l = 1
       break
    else:
       l += 1
print(l)
```

ChatGPT is not really helpful in this case, so thank you for anyone who is willing to help me.

Comment: You're asking why the loop doesn't end the instant the condition becomes false, before control returns to the top of the loop? You think at the instant `l += 1` causes it `l < r` to be false, it should stop running *instantly*, as if you executed a `break`?

Comment: The language documentation and a million free online tutorials are willing to help you, if you read them.

Comment: Download the version specific doc or read the current Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

The first loop runs until i is equal to 50, then you print it meaning that it prints out 50. Then, you add 1 to i again inside the outer loop before it termiantes making it 51. Then, finally you print it out having it print 51.

The outer loop does not terminate the second the condition is false, it terminates at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What this does is create a variable (bucket) l, and store the value 1 in that variable. Then an additional variable r and store the value 2 in that variable. Then, enter a while loop which will end when l is greater than r after execution. The first statement of this loop is itself a separate loop which will end once l is equal to or greater than fifty. In this loop l is only incremented by one so this loop will always end with l being 50 and r being 2. Thusly 50 prints then l is incremented again, compared against 2 and clearly being higher the loop ends on it's first iteration printing 51.

```
l = 1
r = 2
while l < r:
    while l < 50:
        l += 1
    print(l)
    l += 1
    # l < r will be evaluated to true up to this point
print(l)
```

Similar start, create variables l and r. The inside while loop will end with l being set to 50. l is printed, l will always be greater than 2 so l is set to 1 and breaks.

```
l = 1
r = 2
while l < r:
    while l < 50:
        l += 1
    print(l)
    if l > 2:
       l = 1
       break
    else:
       l += 1
print(l)
```

Ultimately, chatGPT and other llms can be helpful to come up with generic boilerplate if you're willing to put up with crap code and fix it. I've seen multiple people in person create garbage because they don't understand anything they've turned in (can't say written), because they've managed to scrape by doing no work on their own. You need to actually practice, your question was, how do I read code.